# Get the current index of a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, indexing, combobox

Say I had a ComboBox with these values:

```
Black
Red
Blue
```

And I have `Red` currently selected. If the user then hits backspace and hits enter I am capturing the `KeyDown` event of the ComboBox.

In this event I want to delete Red from the list of items in the ComboBox.

However, because the text of the ComboBox is blank by the time `KeyDown` is called, the `SelectedIndex` is -1.

Currently I have a workaround that looks like this:

```
private void myComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentMyComboBoxIndex = myComboBox.FindStringExact(myComboBox.Text);
}
```

Which works.. but I was just wondering if there is a better way. It seems like this way could break somehow and it seems a bit messy. Is there no way to get the current index of the ComboBox without having to keep track of it with a member variable and updating it when the index changes?

Thank you.

Comment: There are about 0.01% odds that the user is going to discover this by herself without a manual.  Don't create user interfaces that are hard to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way you are doing is fine. You have to keep the selected index in memory because it returns -1 as the SelectedIndex when the text is deleted. You could take the index in this way too.

```
private void myComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentMyComboBoxIndex = myComboBox.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes I suppose that makes sense. Thanks for the mini-refactor too!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to get the selected item of the combo box as an object:

```
ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
// Initialize combo box
comboBox.Items.Add("Black");
comboBox.Items.Add("Red");
comboBox.Items.Add("Blue");
// Get selected one
string current = (string)comboBox.SelectedItem;
```

Also, the selected item can be easily removed by using one of the following lines of code:

```
// By item
comboBox.Items.Remove(comboBox.SelectedItem);
// By Index
comboBox.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox.SelectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt function to get the index for given value but you can find the index through this function.

**Usage**:

```
int cmbindex  = CmbIdxFindByValue("YourValue", cmbYourComboBox);
```

**Function**:

```
private int CmbIdxFindByValue(string text, ComboBox cmbCd)
    {
        int c = 0; ;
        DataTable dtx = (DataTable)cmbCd.DataSource;
        if (dtx != null)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dx in dtx.Rows)
            {
                if (dx[cmbCd.ValueMember.ToString()].ToString() == text)
                    return c;
                c++;
            }
            return -1;
        }else
            return -1;
    }
```