# How can I read a ComboBox index

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I asked this question a long time ago when I first started learning `C#` and I have come back to try and make sense of it to help the community.

The essence of the question was to read a `comboxbox` index when a user makes a change so the backend code could use the index selected. (there is many questions on stack answering this so I have flagged it as a duplicate)

Comment: What's the error it's giving?

Comment: underlines SelectedIndex in red and says, 'object' does not contain a defintiion for 'SelectedIndex' and no extension method 'SelectedIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found(are you missing ausing directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Just out of interest - what is "_int index2 =  Math.Abs(index);_" for - SelectedIndex is only negative when nothing is selected - otherwise it is the zero-based list offset.

Comment: That's because an object isn't a combobox, so why would it have a selected index? Try `int index = (box as ComboBox).SelectedIndex;`

Comment: it was just to avoid a negative value, not really needed though

Comment: As I pointed out - a negative value (always -1) means nothing selected - if you use index2 & nothing is selected then you will get further errors.

Comment: That works robert.woods, thanks for that, still have a lot to learn!

Comment: @PaulF, ok I will look into that now, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: If you are only ever passing the ComboBox to the method, then why not create the method as "_public static string updateHexListNumbers(string textboxHex, ComboBox box)_" in the first instance - then you wont need to cast the object. If you are passing different types of object to the method, then you will need to check the type before you do the cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered many times already, the `combobox` has a property called `SelectedIndex` for retrieving its index.

Post that answers this: [Get the current index of a ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341351/get-the-current-index-of-a-combobox)